# Laravel Push Notification with Firebase

Tags: php, laravel, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

i want to send push notification from laravel to android client using firebase

how can i do this ?

this is my firebase sdk:

```
<script>

var firebaseConfig = {
apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
authDomain: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
projectId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
appId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
measurementId: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
};



firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

</script>
```

Comment: Did you set up your laravel queue? Did you run `php artisan queue:listen`?

Comment: No, i want to find the complete tutorial and i never worked with queues in laravel

Comment: So you can use laravel documents to setup your queue system, then use this link https://laravel-notification-channels.com/about/ and install firebase notification library. Then you will be able to send notifications using firebase.

Answer (score 0):

The Simple way send push notification from laravel to android client using firebase is curl.

here's my code to send notificatio with FCM.

```
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    /*api_key available in: Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key*/
    $api_key = 'AAAAr...W34:....a5ogzkm3F62';

    $fields = array(
        'to' => "/topics/topicsname",
        'collapse_key' => "type_a",
        'notification' => array (
            "body" => "Body notification",
            "title" => "Title notification",
            "image" => "Image notification"
        ),
        "android" =>  array (
            "notification" => array (
                "image" => "https://link Image notification"
            )
        ),
        'data' => array(
            "body" => "Body notification",
            "title" => "Title notification",
            "link" => "Link notification"
        )
    );

    //header includes Content type and api key
    $headers = array(
        'Content-Type:application/json',
        'Authorization:key=' . $api_key
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if ($result === FALSE) {
        die('FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }
    curl_close($ch);

    return $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

https://techvblogs.com/blog/firebase-push-notification-laravel

https://web-tuts.com/laravel-firebase-push-notification-example/

Code from complete examples from attached posts. I Hope this will help.

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration
    var firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        authDomain: "XXXXXXX.firebaseapp.com",
        projectId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
        storageBucket: "XXXXXXXXXX.appspot.com",
        messagingSenderId: "XXXXXXXXXX",
        appId: "1:XXXXXXXXX:web:XXXXXXXXXXXXX"
    };
    // Initialize Firebase
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

    function initFirebaseMessagingRegistration() {
        messaging.requestPermission().then(function () {
            return messaging.getToken()
        }).then(function(token) {
            
            axios.post("{{ route('fcmToken') }}",{
                _method:"PATCH",
                token
            }).then(({data})=>{
                console.log(data)
            }).catch(({response:{data}})=>{
                console.error(data)
            })

        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(`Token Error :: ${err}`);
        });
    }

    initFirebaseMessagingRegistration();
  
    messaging.onMessage(function({data:{body,title}}){
        new Notification(title, {body});
    });
```